# HandlebarsJS How to check if strings contain special characters

Tags: handlebars.js

I have some strings which I get from a JSON file. Some of them contain the special chracters "-", "--" or are empty

```
{
  "title": "Rihanna - Pour it up"
},
{
  "title" : "Lady Gaga -- Bad Romance"
},
{
  "title" : "Live from Golden Globes"
}
```

So, I have this registerhelper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('titleSplit', function(title) {       
    if(title.indexOf('-') === -1){
        return  new Handlebars.SafeString("<h2>" + title + "</h2>" + "<br />" + "<h2>&nbsp;</h2>");
    }
    if(title.indexOf('--') === -2){
        var t = title.split(" -- ");
        return  new Handlebars.SafeString("<h2>" + t[1] + "</h2>" + " <br/> " + "<h2>" + t[0] + "</h2>");
    } 
    else {
        var t = title.split(" - ");
        return  new Handlebars.SafeString("<h2>" + t[1] + "</h2>" + " <br/> " + "<h2>" + t[0] + "</h2>");
    }
});
```

and in my Handlebars HTML template:

```
<div>
   {{titleSplit title}}
</div>
```

it kind of works alright, except that the titles with `--` are getting displayed like this:

```
Undefined
Lady Gaga -- Bad Romance
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not completely sure on what your desired output should be. But here is the working helper and output

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('titleSplit', function(title) {
  var titles;     
  if(title.indexOf(' - ') >= 0){
    titles = title.split(' - ');
  } else if(title.indexOf(' -- ') >= 0){
    titles = title.split(' -- ');
  } else {
    titles = title.split();
    titles[1] = ''; 
  }

  return  new Handlebars.SafeString(
      "<h2>" + titles[1] + "</h2>" + " <br/> " + "<h2>" + titles[0] + "</h2>");
});

//output

Pour it up

Rihanna
Bad Romance

Lady Gaga

Live from Golden Globes
```